# getting error when pushing RoR app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, heroku

i am trying to push this app to heroku

```
 https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr
```

i did succeed at getting it online

```
 https://morning-atoll-1917.herokuapp.com/
```

however it displays an error, and i would like to know how i find out what is causing this problem? is there some kind of log file? the app is running on the heroku cedar stack with postgresql as db.

i would love if you could help me out here, been struggeling with this for days now.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the output of `heroku logs --tail`?

Comment: i put it in a pastebin here  http://pastebin.com/Uyh5Da69

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after deploying?

Comment: Please add your `db/schema.rb` & `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`, in your question.

Comment: heroku run rake db:migrate did the trick. Thank you!